# Error "Network access is denied" is thrown in my UWP project when I save a file in a network disk

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp

I have an UWP project where I generate a pdf file and then save it to a network disk. This works perfectly fine when running the program using the debugger in Visual Studio. However, when I create the package and install the program through PowerShell the pdf file is not stored and I get the error "System.IO.IOException: Network access is denied".

I already tried adding some capabilities such as Enterprise Authentication, Internet (Client & Server), Internet (Client), Private Networks (Client & Server) but this does not solve my problem.

Comment: Prompt the user with a FileSavePicker to allow them to auth the save location and then you can use the AccessCache to write additional files to the same place (if needed).

Comment: I'm trying to do what you suggested but I haven't been able to find a way to reference FileSavePicker in my xamarin project. I could not find a nuget package for Windows.Storage.Pickers.

Comment: It sounds like you'll need to create a service interface for accessing files/folders in your xamarin project and implement the service in your UWP project directly.

Comment: What I find weird is that what I want to accomplish works just fine in debug mode on Visual Studio. I am able to save the pdf files I am creating. And the problem only happens after generating the package and trying to use that functionality...